# Local Broadcast Manager using an alarm not received by main Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, localbroadcastmanager

I have implemented an alarm manager it is working pretty well and every 15 minutes it is triggered. Now I want to call a **`MainActivity`** method every 15 minutes using the alarm. So I use a Local Broadcaster to the **`MainActivity`** *(knowing that this is the current activity running on my phone)* to transmit the order to start the method. But the problem is that the **`MainActivity`** is not receiving the data on the onReceive method.

**Alarm**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    cont = context;
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();


    String url = intent.getExtras().getString("url");
    Log.w(TAG, "Service " + url);

    new GetJSON_val(){
        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... url) {
            Some Code...

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
            Some Code...

            // I send the broadcast to main Activity
            Log.e("sender", "Broadcasting message");
            Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");

            intent.putExtra("message", "This is my message!");

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(cont).sendBroadcast(intent);

                }
            }
        }
    }.execute(url);


    // End of alarm code

    wl.release();
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
   ...
}
   private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get extra data included in the Intent
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        Log.e("receiver", "Got message: " + message);

    }
};
```

The Local Broadcaster is created in the Alarm class in **`postExecute`** method.

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html#effects_on_process_state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you are performing long running task in `onReceive()` and accessing same `context`

> you should never perform long-running operations in it (there is a timeout of 10 seconds that the system allows before considering the receiver to be blocked and a candidate to be killed).

**Solution**

1. Either you use [goAsync()](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html#effects_on_process_state) .
2. Or use a [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) for background task and sendBroadcast after task is completed .

Comment: Thanks this was the problem